# Trying to change oracle application express port

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-xe

I am trying to change the port for application express form the default 8080 to something I can access from work like 1521. I run exec dbms_xdb.sethttpport('1521'); and then try to connect to http:/MYIPADDRESS:1521/apex and I get a does not exist error.  When I switch it back to 8080 it works fine.  What am I missing here.

Comment: 1521 is used to be the default port for your db. have you tried an other port ?

Comment: I have tried a few. I'm at work right now so I don't have everything I've tried.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a similar question answered here:
https://forums.oracle.com/thread/903663

and here:
http://daust.blogspot.nl/2006/01/xe-changing-default-http-port.html

Perhaps it is of help.

Comment: Well, the second link it is much more interesting, allowing to change http port without strange procedure during install but simply with a small script: `begin  dbms_xdb.sethttpport('8088');  end;`